# NLTK error on nltk-all collection: `info.packages TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Tags: python, ipython, nltk, jupyter

I'm learning NLTK in IPython/Jupyter notebook, Python 3*
Yesterday I could run `nltk.download_shell()`, and use the `l` command to `list` all the packages. I typed `Enter` to page through the entire list without problems.

Today I run `nltk.download_shell()`. I can page through all the 'packages' category. Then it starts the 'collections' category. It lists the info for the `all-corpora` collection, but then fails:

```
Collections:
  [ ] all-corpora......... All the corpora
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bdd77394908d> in <module>()
----> 1 nltk.download_shell()

...Full stack trace...

C:\Users\nnd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py in status(self, info_or_id, download_dir)
    740         # Handle collections:
    741         if isinstance(info, Collection):
--> 742             pkg_status = [self.status(pkg.id) for pkg in info.packages]
    743             if self.STALE in pkg_status:
    744                 return self.STALE

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I debug this code and find the value of the `info` object is:

```
 (Pdb) info
 <Collection all-nltk>
```

I check `info.packages` on the `all-nltk` and indeed the value `is None`.

I suspect that my "index"  (i.e. Downloader `_index`) may be outdated or wrong, but I don't know much about the index. Any ideas how to prevent this error?

*Specific versions:

```
import sys; print(sys.version)
3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)
3.2.2
```

**EDIT**

May be related to an error I get earlier , the error which prints once and I can only reproduce if I try to *force* an `_update_index(...)` (i.e. by setting the `self.INDEX_TIMEOUT` to some amount *lower* than the `time.time()-self._index_timestamp`):

```
(Pdb) self.INDEX_TIMEOUT = 3000
(Pdb) self._update_index()
removing collection member with no package: hmm_treebank_pos_tagger
removing collection member with no package: hmm_treebank_pos_tagger
*** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'


C:\Users\nnd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py in _update_index(self, url)
    855                     queue.extend(child.children)
    856                 else:
--> 857                     packages[child.id] = child
    858             collection.packages = packages.values()
    859 

 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And when I check which package is a string, it's `'maxent_treebank_pos_tagger'`:

```
 ...
 <Package ycoe>
 <Package rslp>
 maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-6-bdd77394908d> in <module>()
 ----> 1 nltk.download_shell()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I describe in my OP, I think this was due to a change in the last 24 hours; a change since yesterday. The change was made to the `index.xml`, but the code in `downloader.py` doesn't handle the change very well.

Specifically [this commit (~16 hours ago)](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/commit/12ae9e1b4c4dcf92bf8956bfcf9cffc86be144f6#diff-7323624b83e1dea8ba3cdf1fdfeb8d5c) removed the package `hmm_treebank_pos_tagger`, but did not remove the references to that package (for example [the reference in this line in `all-nltk` of the `index.xml`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/index.xml#L270)) .

I think the effect is that `downloader.py` fails when [deleting-item-in-list-while-iterating-the-list](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/downloader.py#L853). `downloader.py` fails to convert the *next* item in the list from a `string` to a `Package`; the next item's ID is `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger`.

This causes the error in my OP "EDIT" section, (`'str' object has no attribute 'id'`), which causes the error I originally asked about (`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`)...

I [commented on the commit here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/commit/12ae9e1b4c4dcf92bf8956bfcf9cffc86be144f6#comments)...

**EDIT**

I forked a branch and made a pull-request to remove references, avoiding the root problem. You can use this copy of the index (with references removed) to list the packages without error (of course `hmm_treebank_pos_tagger` will not be included!)

```
server_index_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theredpea/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml'
d = nltk.downloader.Downloader(server_index_url=server_index_url)
nltk.downloader.DownloaderShell(d).run()
```

**EDIT**

My specific `index.xml` is *not* necessary anymore, my change was merged (cool!); the [master `index.xml`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/pull/105) has removed the "orphaned references" as I call them, so I expect no one will experience this issue again :)